# How to pull data in a table and output it as JSON in Supabase

Tags: json, plpgsql, supabase

I am new to supabase and was using the SQL Editor to create functions that I can use in my Flutterflow App. The problem I am encountering is grabbing the data and output it as a JSON. I can do this but in table form but I need it in JSON to alter it again as well. Below is the code I currently having which outputs as json but only a single row (maybe because I used record as data type)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dashboard_company_registration(start_date date, end_date date)
RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE
  t_id integer;
  t_plan_name text;
  t_created_at timestamp;
  t_count integer;
  datas record;
  jsondata jsonb;
  current_date date := start_date;
  date_array date[];
BEGIN
  SELECT
    p.id, p.plan_name, pr.created_at, count(p.id) as count
  INTO datas
  FROM profiles as pr
  JOIN user_subscription_plans as usp
    ON usp.user_id = pr.id
  JOIN plans as p
    ON usp.plans_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id, p.plan_name, pr.created_at
  ORDER BY pr.created_at;

  return json_build_object('data', datas);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql security definer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need a SQL query wrapped in a SQL function.
I suppose that you have omitted the `where` clause in your question.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dashboard_company_registration(start_date date, end_date date)
RETURNS JSON LANGUAGE SQL security definer AS
$$
select json_agg(to_json(t.*)) from
( 
  -- your query w/o INTO and a WHERE clause added
  SELECT p.id, p.plan_name, pr.created_at, count(p.id) as count
  FROM profiles as pr
  JOIN user_subscription_plans as usp ON usp.user_id = pr.id
  JOIN plans as p ON usp.plans_id = p.id

  -- added by me
  WHERE pr.created_at::date between start_date and end_date  

  GROUP BY p.id, p.plan_name, pr.created_at
  ORDER BY pr.created_at
) as t
$$;
```

Yet I am not sure that you need a function at all. Why not use just the query with parameters (`:start_date` and `:end_date` for example)